# UWP MapControl, possible to display only coastlines / country boundaries?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, uwp-maps

I'm getting started with learning UWP apps using Visual Studio 2017 and I'd like to create a map that displays only coastlines and country borders, i.e: No roads, city names, or anything else.
I've been googling and reading tutorials but can't figure out if this is even possible, let alone how to do it. The closest I can find is MapStyle, but that doesn't seem to offer a solution.

Any ideas, or is this simply not possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The upcoming release of Windows 10 will have an API on the map control that will allow you to customize the visible elements of the map. You can play with this on insider builds now.

Comment: Source/documentation?

Comment: yes, some documentation would be nice. i had a look but didnt find much.

Comment: Updated MSDN documentation should be available soon

Comment: Documentation is now available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapstylesheet